# initializing php class with default array

Tags: php, arrays, class

here's my php code:

```
$settings = array(
    'width'         => 500,
    'height'        => 300
);
$mygrid->init($settings);
```

class code:

```
class mygrid
{
    function __construct($settings)
    {
       $default_settings = array(
        'width'         => 500,
        'height'        => 300
       )
    }

}
```

i'd like to kinda merge both arrays in order to have a fallback to default values, eg. when creating an instance which sets width only:

```
$settings = array('width' => 800);
$mygrid->init($settings);
```

the class should use the default height of 300

thanks

Comment: The question is unclear in its current state. Please edit the text above and add more details, especially what it is you want to do. What does "depending on which variables are passed" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you look at [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-merge.php) ?

```
function init($settings) {
    $defaults = aray('width' => 250, 'height' => 300, 'color' => 'black');
    $this->settings = array_merge($defaults, $settings);

}
```

With your example, the result will be:

```
$this->settings = array('width' => 300, 'height' => 500, 'color' => 'black');
```

Every key passed in your `$settings` parameter will override the equivalent in `$defaults`.